# Loop into an array to build a select with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've the following array in PHP:

```
$countries = array(
    array('CTY_Code' => 'AF', 'CTY_en' => 'Afghanistan', 'CTY_fr' => 'Afghanistan'),
    array('CTY_Code' => 'AL', 'CTY_en' => 'Albania', 'CTY_fr' => 'Albanie')
);
```

How can I loop into this to have a select like this:

```
<select>
    <option value='AF'>Afghanistan</option>
    <option value='AL'>Albania</option>
</select>
```

What I tried:

```
<select>
<?
foreach($CTY_Code as $key => $CTY_en) {
    echo '<option value="'.$CTY_Code.'">'.$CTY_en.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `foreach($countries as $arr) { echo '<option value="'.$arr['CTY_Code'].'">'.$arr['CTY_en'].'</option>'; }` You have to iterate over `$countries` instead of `$CTY_Code` (which doesn't even exist anyway), and then get `CTY_Code` and `CTY_en` from the sub-array of `$arr`

Comment: I don't understand why the down-votes! the question is clear, well formatted, specific, shows the OP efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array.

```
$countries = array(
    array('CTY_Code' => 'AF', 'CTY_en' => 'Afghanistan', 'CTY_fr' => 'Afghanistan'),
    array('CTY_Code' => 'AL', 'CTY_en' => 'Albania', 'CTY_fr' => 'Albanie')
);
```

Here is your code

```
echo "<select><option>--select country--</option>";
foreach ($countries as $countrykey => $countryvalue) {
        echo "<option value=".$countryvalue['CTY_Code'].">".$countryvalue['CTY_en']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

another way to php in html

```
<select><option>--select option--</option>
<?php foreach ($countries as $countrykey => $countryvalue) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$countryvalue['CTY_Code'];?>"><?=$countryvalue['CTY_en'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
   echo '<option value="'.$value['CTY_Code'].'">'.$value['CTY_en'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$countries = array(
    array('CTY_Code' => 'AF', 'CTY_en' => 'Afghanistan', 'CTY_fr' => 'Afghanistan'),
    array('CTY_Code' => 'AL', 'CTY_en' => 'Albania', 'CTY_fr' => 'Albanie')
);
echo sprintf(
    "<select>%s\n</select>",
    implode("", array_map(function ($value) {
        return sprintf("\n\t<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", $value['CTY_Code'], $value['CTY_en']);
    }, $countries))
);
```

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/pNpWC)

That will give you:

```
<select>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
</select>
```